Pusher error 0A000438:SSL routines::tlsv1 alert internal error
I'm using Laravel Reverb on my live server. I've configured it to run with Nginx. However, I'm getting the following error whenever I try to broadcast an event using Reverb.
Pusher error: cURL error 35: OpenSSL/3.0.13: error:0A000438:SSL routines::tlsv1 alert internal error (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://ws.{domain_name}.app/apps/app_123/events?auth_key=key_123&auth_timestamp=1720515425&auth_version=1.0&body_md5=bea8622c84688147d1e7823170cee4fe&auth_signature=4f8b1ab60ac7f3e73a1746fc32ad4dedb2a50e9e625c84525d2d7f1c9099bc67.

This is the reverb stuff from my env:
 REVERB_APP_ID={app_id}
 REVERB_APP_KEY={app_key}
 REVERB_APP_SECRET={app_secret]
 REVERB_HOST="ws.{domain_name}.app"
 REVERB_SCHEME=https
 REVERB_SERVER_PORT=8080
 REVERB_PORT=443

This is my nginx configuration:
 # Define the server for {domain_name}.app and www.{domain_name}.app
 server {
     listen 80;
     server_name {domain_name}.app www.{domain_name}.app;
 
     # Define the root directory for the site
     root /home/digitalocean/{domain_name}.app/current/public;
 
     # Enable Gzip compression
     gzip on;
     gzip_types text/plain application/json text/css application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/svg+xml;
 
     # Enable Zstd compression (requires Nginx to be compiled with Zstd support)
     # Uncomment the lines below if Zstd is supported
     # zstd on;
     # zstd_types text/plain application/json text/css application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/svg+xml;
 
     location ~ ^/(app|apps)/ {
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
         proxy_set_header Scheme $scheme;
         proxy_set_header SERVER_PORT $server_port;
         proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
 
         proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8080;
     }
 
     # PHP-FPM configuration
     location ~ \.php$ {
         include fastcgi_params;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
     }
 }
 
 # Define the server for client.{domain_name}.app
 server {
     listen 80;
     server_name client.{domain_name}.app;
 
     # Enable Gzip compression
     gzip on;
     gzip_types text/plain application/json text/css application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/svg+xml;
 
     # Reverse proxy to backend server
     location / {
         proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3000;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
     }
 }
 
 # Define the server for customer.{domain_name}.app
 server {
     listen 80;
     server_name customer.{domain_name}.app;
 
     # Enable Gzip compression
     gzip on;
     gzip_types text/plain application/json text/css application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/svg+xml;
 
     # Reverse proxy to backend server
     location / {
         proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:4000;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
     }
 }

Note: I've tried setting the REVERB_SCHEME as HTTP and the REVERB_PORT as 80; however, the error persists.

I have no idea what Reverb is, and it isn't completely clear what is generating the error you show nor where it shows up, but it quotes what I understand to be your server: https://ws.{domain_name}.app/apps/app_123/events?... - note https.  The nginx config you've shown does not include any support for https.  So my wild  guess is that some service is attempting to make an https request to your server, but your server is not configured to handle that.  That correlates with the technical content of the error too, which suggests SSL problems.

@Don'tPanic You're right. I'd forgotten to add an SSL certification. I managed to add one using Let'sEncrypt. Thank you!
